# Raster values out of range when exporting a spectral index

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat, imagecollection

My goal is to export monthly bands and indices from Landsat 9. Here is my approach for the bands (I know it's not the most elegant way but I think it's working):

```
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2');

Map.centerObject(table);

//Create mask function
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 2, 3 and 5 are water, cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  var waterBitMask = (1 << 2);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

for (var y = 2023; y < 2024; y++) {
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
var landsat1 = landsat.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(i, i, 'month'))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                      .filterBounds(table)
                      .map(maskL8sr);
                      
var landsat2 = landsat1.select('SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7', 'ST_B10');
    
//Calculate the median for B10, multiply by scale factor
//(0.1), and clip to country polygon
var mean2 = landsat1.select('ST_B10').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0).clip(table);

//Create variable for each band
var B2 = landsat2.select('SR_B2').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B3 = landsat2.select('SR_B3').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B4 = landsat2.select('SR_B4').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B5 = landsat2.select('SR_B5').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B6 = landsat2.select('SR_B6').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B7 = landsat2.select('SR_B7').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B10 = landsat2.select('ST_B10').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0).clip(table);

var B10 = B10.subtract(273.15);

// bands I want to export
var bandSpectralList = [B4, B5, B10];

var desc = "";

for (var banda = 0; banda < bandSpectralList.length; banda++) {
  
  switch (bandSpectralList[banda]) {
        case B2:
            desc = "blue";
            break;
        case B3:
            desc = "green";
            break;
        case B4:
            desc = "red";
            break;
        case B5:
            desc = "nir";
            break;
         case B6:
            desc = "swir1";
            break;
         case B7:
            desc = "swir2";
            break;
         case B10:
            desc = "tirs";
            break;
        // Add more cases as needed
        default:
            desc = "wrong_name";
            break;
    }
    
var currentBand = bandSpectralList[banda];

Export.image.toDrive({
image: currentBand,
description: desc.toString() + "_" + y + "_" +  ee.Number(i).format('%02d').getInfo(),
scale: 130, //100 for Band10
maxPixels: 1000000000000,
region: table, 
crs: 'EPSG:3309'
});
}
}
}
```

Now assuming that I want to create a spectral band, called nbi, and export it. The formula is `var nbi = (red * swir2) / nir`. When I try to export the monthly nbi for the various years:

**1st try**

I just calculate the index as shown above and I add it to the `bandSpectralList` and in the case section, like so:

```
// bands I want to export
var bandSpectralList = [B4, B5, B10, nbi];

var desc = "";

for (var banda = 0; banda < bandSpectralList.length; banda++) {
  
  switch (bandSpectralList[banda]) {
        case B2:
            desc = "blue";
            break;
        case B3:
            desc = "green";
            break;
        case B4:
            desc = "red";
            break;
        case B5:
            desc = "nir";
            break;
         case B6:
            desc = "swir1";
            break;
         case B7:
            desc = "swir2";
            break;
         case B10:
            desc = "tirs";
            break;
         case nbi:
            desc = "nbi";
            break;
        // Add more cases as needed
        default:
            desc = "wrong_name";
            break;
    }
```

But this is produces an image with wrong range of values.
[image: nbi]

As you can see there is no spatial variability in the image because very few pixels (outliers) distort the image.

**2nd try**

Following [this](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_api_06#mapping-a-function-over-a-collection) example, I tried to create a function and `map` over a collection. So outside the `for` loop, I added:

```
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = mean1.select('SR_B4_mean').multiply(mean1.select('SR_B7_mean')).divide(mean1.select('SR_B5_mean')).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};
```

But from there I am not sure how to proceed. I tried a lot of things and depending on what I tried I am getting error(s). How can I export the nbi index with proper pixel values?

[Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5c77f80769ed6db1c2908b895e1c25b5) to the code for exporting just the bands. [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/nikostziokas/test/la_54009) to the shp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following function before the first `for` loop:

```
// calculate nbi index
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.select('SR_B4').subtract(image.select('SR_B6')).divide(image.select('SR_B6')).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};
```

and then after the `var B10 = B10.subtract(273.15);` I added this:

```
// Map the function over the image collection
var withNDVI = landsat2.map(addNDVI).select('NDVI').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(table);
```

and finally, I added in the 3rd `for`:

```
  case withNDVI:
    desc = "nbi";
    break;
```

and it worked perfectly.

The complete code:

```
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2');

Map.centerObject(table);

//Create mask function
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 2, 3 and 5 are water, cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  var waterBitMask = (1 << 2);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.select('SR_B4').subtract(image.select('SR_B6')).divide(image.select('SR_B6')).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

//Create Image Collection for Landsat 8 BOA, filtering data from April 2013 to December 2013
//filtering the tiles which intersect India, selecting the predefined bands (VIS, NIR and SWIR)
//Display results
for (var y = 2022; y < 2023; y++) {
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
var landsat1 = landsat.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(i, i, 'month'))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                      .filterBounds(table)
                      .map(maskL8sr);
                      
var landsat2 = landsat1.select('SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7', 'ST_B10');

//Calculate the median for each band (B2 to B7), multiply by scale factor
//(0.0001), and clip to country polygon
//var mean1 = landsat.select('SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);

//Calculate the median for B10, multiply by scale factor
//(0.1), and clip to country polygon
var mean2 = landsat1.select('ST_B10').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0).clip(table);

//Create variable for each band
var B2 = landsat2.select('SR_B2').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B3 = landsat2.select('SR_B3').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B4 = landsat2.select('SR_B4').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B5 = landsat2.select('SR_B5').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B6 = landsat2.select('SR_B6').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B7 = landsat2.select('SR_B7').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B10 = landsat2.select('ST_B10').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0).clip(table);

var B10 = B10.subtract(273.15);

// Map the function over the image collection
var withNDVI = landsat2.map(addNDVI).select('NDVI').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(table);

var bandSpectralList = [withNDVI];

var desc = "";

for (var banda = 0; banda < bandSpectralList.length; banda++) {
  
  switch (bandSpectralList[banda]) {
        case B2:
            desc = "blue";
            break;
            
        case B3:
            desc = "green";
            break;
            
        case B4:
            desc = "red";
            break;
            
        case B5:
            desc = "nir";
            break;
            
         case B6:
            desc = "swir1";
            break;
            
         case B7:
            desc = "swir2";
            break;
            
         case B10:
            desc = "tirs";
            break;

        //case evi:
            //desc = "evi";
            //break;
            
        case withNDVI:
            desc = "nbi";
            break;
            
        //case gndvi:
            //desc = "gndvi";
            //break;
            
        //case ndbi:
            //desc = "ndbi";
            //break;
            
        //case ebbi:
          //  desc = "ebbi";
            //break;
            
        //case nbi:
          //  desc = "nbi";
            //break;
            
         //case nbai:
           // desc = "nbai";
            //break;
            
        //case mbai:
          //desc = "mbai";
          //break;
        // Add more cases as needed
        default:
            desc = "wrong_name";
            break;
    }
    
var currentBand = bandSpectralList[banda];

Export.image.toDrive({
image: currentBand,
description: desc.toString() + "_" + y + "_" +  ee.Number(i).format('%02d').getInfo(),
scale: 130, //100 for Band10
maxPixels: 1000000000000,
region: table, 
crs: 'EPSG:3309'
});
}
}
}
```